# addthis custom services not working

Tags: addthis

I want to use the addthis custom services for my project. I tried following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var addthis_config = {
  services_custom: [{
          name: "AddThis",
          url: "http://addthis.com/bookmark.php?url=http://purab.com&title=purabtitle",
          icon: "http://addthis.com/images/addthis32.gif"
  }]
  }
 </script>

<a class="addthis_button_addthis.com 32x32"></a>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-5281ee5c7439355a"></script>
<!-- AddThis Button END -->
```

I got following code snippet from following URL:
[Addthis Custom Services API](http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381245-custom-services)

But code is not working. I found following article which talks about same.
http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/questions/1378256-custom-service?t=89322
I asked question to there support but I did not got any answer yet.

Anybody worked on addthis custom services

Answer (score 0):

So I copied your example and got it to work by replacing http://purab.com with {{url}} and purabtitle with {{title}} in the url property so it should look like this:

```
url: "http://addthis.com/bookmark.php?url={{url}}&title={{title}}",
```

Give that a try and let me know if it's still not working.